# PC suite for android mobile phone

Tags: 14.04

Okay I have an android cell phone and need a pc suite to connect with my PC that runs ubuntu 14.04. Anyone knows one?

Comment: What functions specifically are you trying to access?

Answer (score 3):

Try [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It is easy to use: connect the phone to the same network as your PC (Wi-Fi or USB tethering) then use your browser to connect to the phone.

Comment: My phone is the alcatel one touch 980, doesn't have google play and Airdroid is not possible to install

Comment: @user248157 You can install AirDroid from [Aptoide](http://ibatista.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.sand.airdroid/67/5499467/AirDroid%20-%20Best%20Device%20Manager) or [1mobile](http://www.1mobile.com/airdroid---best-device-manager-347024.html) or download the apk from [here](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) or [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/lx8z2zw3vbzh58c/com.sand.airdroid.apk).

Comment: It says ''a parsing error has occurred" -> can't install.

Comment: @user248157 Which version of Android do you have?